# Force wget to timeout

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wget

How can I force wget to stop after X seconds?

I have a script that downloads images and from time to time it gets stuck and refuses to "timeout".

What I've tried:

```
--tries=3 --connect-timeout=30
```

From `ps aux`:

```
root     26543  0.0  0.0  38636  1656 ?        S    20:40   0:00 wget -nc --tries=3 --connect-timeout=30 --restrict-file-names=nocontrol -O 18112012/image.jpg http://site/image.jpg
```

Comment: Have you tried the `--timeout` (or `-T`) option?

Comment: yes... everything from wget man

Comment: Are you sure you tried `wget -nc --tries=3 -T30 --restrict-file-names=nocontrol -O 18112012/image.jpg http://site/image.jpg`? I've never had problems like you're describing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the wget command as a background process and send a SIGKILL to forcibly kill it after sleeping for a certain amount of time.

```
wget ... &
wget_pid=$!
counter=0
timeout=60
while [[ -n $(ps -e) | grep "$wget_pid") && "$counter" -lt "$timeout" ]]
do
    sleep 1
    counter=$(($counter+1))
done
if [[ -n $(ps -e) | grep "$wget_pid") ]]; then
    kill -s SIGKILL "$wget_pid"
fi
```

**Explanation:**

- `wget ... &` - the `&` notation at the end runs the command in the background as opposed to the foreground
- `wget_pid=$!` - `$!` is a special shell variable that contains the process id of the most recently executed command. Here we save it to a variable called `wget_pid`.
- `while [[ -n $(ps -e) | grep "$wget_pid") && "$counter" -lt "$timeout" ]]` - Look for the process every one second, if it's still there, keep waiting until a timeout limit.
- `kill -s SIGKILL "$wget_pid"` - We use `kill` to forcibly kill the wget process running in the background by sending it a [SIGKILL signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal).

Comment: What if `wget` succeeds? You'll throw randomly a `SIGKILL`?

Comment: how can i skip "sleep" if file has been already downloaded?

Comment: Rewrote the script to make it a bit more robust and address the skipping of sleep times issue

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf is there evidence that it's harmful to send a SIGKILL to nothing?

Comment: @kojiro depending on implementation, technically pids can get reused; so it's theoretically possible for it to hit another process.

Comment: @kojiro Why to nothing?

Comment: @sampson-chen the probability of that happening is near zero. Exactly zero if you use the job number instead of the pid.

Answer (score 16):

Easiest way is to use the `timeout(1)` command, part of GNU coreutils, so available pretty much anywhere bash is installed:

```
timeout 60 wget ..various wget args..
```

or if you want to hard-kill wget if its running too long:

```
timeout -s KILL 60 wget ..various wget args..
```

Comment: You do know bash is installed on every Mac, which do not have a GNU userland, right?

Comment: @kojiro: The question is tagged `ubuntu` which includes GNU coreutils, and it can readily be installed on a mac if you want it.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it should've been migrated to askubuntu.com. >;)

Comment: This is definitely the easiest and safest way. `man timeout` will show other options. I would personally not use the `-s KILL` option directly, but maybe use the `-k` option, something like `timeout -k 5 60 wget ..various wget args..` (to give a 5 extra seconds chance to `wget` before being `KILL`ed). This answer deserves `+1`.

Answer (score 1):

Recent `wget` versions (1.19+, at least) allow to set a timeout:

```
  -T,  --timeout=SECONDS           set all timeout values to SECONDS
       --dns-timeout=SECS          set the DNS lookup timeout to SECS
       --connect-timeout=SECS      set the connect timeout to SECS
       --read-timeout=SECS         set the read timeout to SECS
       --waitretry=SECONDS         wait 1..SECONDS between retries of a retrieval
  -t,  --tries=NUMBER              set number of retries to NUMBER (0 unlimits)
```

#### Example

```
wget --timeout 4 --tries 1 "https://www.google.com/"
```

This example will try once to connect and get URL https://www.google.com. After 4 seconds it will timeout.

Comment: From what versions up exactly is this applicable for this new parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Community wiki because this is mostly a copy of sampson-chen's answer, but I wanted to point out a couple of things:

```
wget ... &
# Strictly speaking you can just use the job number,
# which is probably %1, but saving the pid is also fine.
wget_pid=$! 
counter=0
timeout=60
# use kill -0 to check if a pid is still running
while kill -0 "$wget_pid" && (( counter < timeout )); do
    sleep 1
    (( counter++ ))
done
# if killing nothing is distasteful, use kill -0 one more time.
# also think a SIGKILL is overkill since the question doesn't imply wget needs it.
kill -0 "$wget_pid" && kill "$wget_pid"
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently noticed that wget **1.14** was silently **ignoring the --timeout** option, it worked ok when I updated it to **1.19**